# How to give different empty message for different search option in RadSearchBox?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, telerik

I have a telerik:RadSearchBox in which,there are three option for searching .For different option the empty message must be different.

For example
1)For Tag / Serial:  “Search Tag or Serial Number.”
2)For Staff:  “Search Staff ID or Name”
3)For Students:  “Search Student ID or Name.”

```
 <telerik:RadSearchBox RenderMode="Lightweight"   runat="server" ID="RadSearchBox1" Width="250" DropDownSettings-Height="100" MaxResultCount="20">
 <SearchContext ShowDefaultItem="false">
<Items>
<telerik:SearchContextItem Text="Tag / Serial" Key="Tag" />
<telerik:SearchContextItem Text="Staff" Key ="Staff" />
<telerik:SearchContextItem Text="Student" Key ="Student" />
</Items>
</SearchContext>
</telerik:RadSearchBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture the change of the selection in the `SearchContext`, by hooking a click event to the `.rsbListItem` (which are actually the `SearchContextItem`) at the `OnClientLoad` client-side event of the `RadSearchBox`. Then, depending on the selection, you can use `set_emptyMessage("some message")`, in order to set it accordingly. Consider the bellow implementation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnClientLoad(sender) {
        $telerik.$(".rsbListItem").on('click', function (e) {
            switch (this.innerHTML) {
                case "Tag / Serial":
                    sender.set_emptyMessage("Search Tag or Serial Number");
                    break;
                case "Staff":
                    sender.set_emptyMessage("Search Staff ID or Name");
                    break;
                case "Student":
                    sender.set_emptyMessage("Search Student ID or Name");
                    break;
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```